# Why Ethernet webclient fails to initiate?

Tags: ethernet-shield

I use the Ethernet shield with an Uno and create a web client. If I put a delay like one second for initialization it works fine. However if I wait for it in a while loop (like waiting for the serial, and as mentioned in Arduino docs) it never gets out of the loop that means the client instance is null.

I found this method on Arduino website in an example code:

```js
while(!client) { ; } // waiting to get ready
```

Here's the code; if I uncomment it will stay there. Also the same with providing the MAC argument only.

```js
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xEE };
char server[] = "www.google.com";    // name address for Google (using DNS)

IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 213);

EthernetClient client;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ;
  }

  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  delay(1000);
  //while(!client){ ; }
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}
```

Comment: Show the rest of your particular code.

Comment: @josecanuc #include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xEE };
char server[] = "www.google.com";    // name address for Google (using DNS)

IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 213);

EthernetClient client;

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) { ; }

  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  delay(1000);
  //while(!client){ ; }
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}

Comment: Code in comments is unreadable. Edit it into the post.

Comment: What is the commented line supposed to achieve...?

Comment: @majenko I want to check that if the hardware is functional and ready and my client object has created successfully so I can start communication. Instead of putting a blind delay(n) and hope for the best.

Comment: Then you want to do such things as check that you have a valid IP address from your DHCP server. Your "client" object will only be in any way valid once you have tried making a connection to a remote server.

Comment: @majenko then I think the only way left to let a client or server knowing it's possible for them to start is polling the Ethernet.begin() for some time / tries . Then rising an error and halt. Or is there a better way?  A server.begin() is a null type and server.available() is a client object type. None of them return an error.

Comment: You try opening a connection. If it works you can open a connection. If it doesn't then you can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `while(!client){ ; }` line can never do anything useful.

It is used to wait for a client socket to connect to a remote port. You aren't connecting to a remote port (that `client` object is doing *nothing*), so how it can never succeed.

It's like saying "Do nothing, and tell me when you're done".

I don't know what you hope to achieve with that line of code...

Comment: So what does it serve [here](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/IfEthernetClient)

Comment: is the linked example wrong?

Comment: Most likely. I can't see what they think they are doing there. That test can never pass unless a connection has been attempted, and no connection has been attempted.

Answer (score 0):

What you write is not a function but a variable. And the variable will not change its value (unless you have some interrupt and it is a global variable).

so you need to change 'client' to some function you want to call, probably 'client.xxx()' where xxx is the name of the function you want to call (possibly with parameters).

Comment: Actually it's an instance of an object with an int operator. It returns whether the socket is connected or not. That may be interrupt driven, or it may be done through yield(), which may explain it working with delay(), since delay() calls yeild().

Comment: I guess you're right but the code is available at [link](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/IfEthernetClient)